# Contact form 7 - Can't seem to get my label and field in one line

Tags: wordpress, nlp, alignment, contact-form-7

I am trying to create a natural language style contact form using contact form 7 but can't seem to get my label and fields to align. Each one displays on a separate line, not next to each other. Have tried a few different CSS tricks but nothing has worked. Any help?

I have tried floating the fields left and right, I have tried using divs to get them on the same line.

My name is [text your-name] and I am looking for [select TypeofMortgage "Bridging Finance" "Auction Finance" "Refurbishment Finance" "Development Finance"] for a property worth £[number number-603]

The best way to reach me us by [select contact "Phone""email"] at [text phone] or you can reach me by [select contact "Phone""email"] at [text your-email]

[submit "Chat soon"]

I really need this to display as a natural language, fill in the blanks style form.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using float.

First of all Create 1 Div and inside that Create one Div for Label and another one for input field.

and then use this css.

```
<style>
.main-box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 360px;
  height: 360px;
}
#labelBox {
  float: left;
}
#inputBox {
  float: right;
}
</style>
```